# Choosing point nearest to initial point in lattice to maximize convexity

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, polygons, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

On lattice world i start from some point.

[image]

At each time-step i claim $n$ neighboring points as ordered randomly. So at $t=1$, i claim $3$ points,

$t=2; 2$ points,

$t=3; 6$ points and so on.

At any time instant, the convex hull of the points chosen should have  maximum convexity. One strategy is to choose points closest to the initial point. Could it be proved that this is the best strategy?

Basically the best strategy should lead to circular expansion. So question is does this strategy ensure circular expansion?

Comment: I don't understand how you are choosing points... EDIT: why are there 3 points chosen in the first timestep instead of all four adjacent points?

Comment: So an external policy is commanding me to choose certain number of points every time-step.

Comment: for simplicity one could assume that one point has to be selected every time-step.

Comment: It's not obvious to me whether maximizing convexity by the greedy algorithm at each step actually reaches the maximum after $n$ steps. I think that is your question - whether the greedy algorithm is optimal for this problem?